# Identify gaps in N dimensional data set

Tags: geometry, algorithms

We have an interesting problem we need to resolve here, we're using C# .NET 4.0 but the language should be irrelevant as it's a mathematical problem.

**Problem**: we need to identify gaps in N dimensional data set and report exactly where those gaps are back to the user.

For example, let's assume we're working with 3-D, so we have this object `Quote` with 6 properties: `TermFrom, TermTo, AgeFrom, AgetTo, AmountFrom, AmountTo` and boundaries we need to cover: `MinTerm = 0, MaxTerm = 5, MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 5, MinAmount = 0, MaxAmount = 5`. Assuming all minimums are `0` and maximums are `5` just to simplify the example, albeit they could be different. So, the data we need to check for gaps in is the following data set:

```
Quote[] {
  {  TermFrom=0, TermTo=3, AgeFrom=0, AgetTo=4, AmountFrom=0, AmountTo=2  },
  {  TermFrom=4, TermTo=5, AgeFrom=0, AgetTo=5, AmountFrom=3, AmountTo=5  }
```

This dataset contains gaps for combinations: `{ Term: 0-5, Age: 4-5, Amount: 0-2 } and { Term: 0-3, Age: 0-5, Amount: 2-5 }, { Term: 4-5, Age: 0-5, Amount: 0-2 }` (i think)

i.e. if you imagine a cube and the datasets are parts of this cube, to calculated total volume of all datasets must be equal to the cube's volume. And we need to identify where the gaps are in this cube if its volume isn't full.

All of this is required with more dimensions: 4 and 5, but it's a lot harder to visualise. I was hoping there is some sort of mathematical solution to this problem, which we could translate to c# code.

Comment: Define "gap."${}$

Comment: I have no idea what the right tag is, but it is *not* dimension theory.

Answer (score 0):

With $6$ possible values in $3$ dimensions you would need $6^3=216$ data points to fill the cube.  The number gets larger quickly as the number of dimensions increases.  It would be possible to cut the cube into $2^3=8$ pieces of half the size in each dimension and check that there are points (or even about the same number of points) in each octant.  But checking that there is not a random $3 \times 3 \times 3$ block without points seems rather difficult.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the problem is there are more than 6 values, because some of the properties are of decimal type. For instance, AmountFrom/To is currency, e.g. has 2 decimal point precision. Would you simply treat it as more points, e.g. one for each penny?